# SELECT maximum and minimum value from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get the `fname` and `lname` of the person that makes the most money and the person that makes the least.

I am looking for a solution that uses only one query

```
Select fname, lname
from Employees
where Salary =51,000
and Salary =$28,000;
```

I tried to figure this out but I could not.

It is using subqueries and I am having a really hard time figuring it out. It is said to use only 1 query.

Comment: Your title is terrible

Comment: I'm sorry, what is a better title for the help that I am seeking, I'll take any help for this

Comment: Try to understand what problem is a superset of the problem you are trying to solve. For example, "adding two numbers" is a superset of the problem: "adding 1 and 2".

Comment: It would be useful to know what SQL product you are using. MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL?

Comment: Can subqueries or unions be used?

Comment: Search for "top and bottom sql <DBMS>" (DBMS: Oralce, MS Sql, MySql...). Also your sql searches for a employee whose salary is 51000 AND also 28000. Since Salary is a single column, this will always be false.

Comment: It seems like the teacher is saying no, and I'm using access database to answer these questions from the database provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select fname, lname, Salary
from Employees
where Salary = (select min(Salary) from Employees) or 
    Salary = (select max(Salary) from Employees)
```

EDIT: if you know the values of the top/bottom salary, use this:

```
Select fname, lname
from Employees
where Salary =51,000
OR
Salary =$28,000;
```

Emphasis on OR.

Comment: Is it normal for first year sql learners to be this confused on the subquery subject? or Is it just me?

Comment: What are you confused about? The subquery is just a query that returns a single value. The value is then used in a comparison expression in the main query.